# Laravel's artisan is refusing to work sometimes on Homestead

Tags: php, laravel, command-line-interface, homestead, laravel-artisan

I'm trying to run

```
php artisan migrate
```

but I got error

```
[ErrorException]
  stream_socket_client(): unable to connect to tcp://10.20.10.10:4000 (Connection timed out)
```

I'm working on Homestead. It does work sometimes, but sometimes it just doesn't. I don't know why

@edit: I'm using RabbitMQ, firewall is not a problem and database works fine (in application at least)

Comment: Seems like your database connection is not configured correctly.

Comment: try to disable your firewall and test it !

Comment: You are using any third party server in your application? Like node for socket or Rabitmq server. Please provide more info about your setup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try searching the code for the IP that you're trying to connect? There could be some things that are shutting down the code when you're trying to run the project.

Answer (score 0):

Can you verify that your RabbitMQ Server is running? This usually happens when RabbitMQ server is not running at all. You can check the output of `rabbitmqctl` or can simply run the start command to see if it is already running properly. 
`service rabbitmq-server start`.
You should see something similar to following output if it is already running.

> ERROR: node with name "rabbit" already running on "localhost"

Otherwise it should start the server and output would be similar to this;

> 

```
RabbitMQ 3.6.12. Copyright (C) 2007-2017 Pivotal Software, Inc.
  ##  ##      Licensed under the MPL.  See http://www.rabbitmq.com/
  ##  ##
  ##########  Logs: /usr/local/var/log/rabbitmq/rabbit@localhost.log
  ######  ##        /usr/local/var/log/rabbitmq/rabbit@localhost-sasl.log
  ##########
              Starting broker...
 completed with 9 plugins.
```

I hope this helps to diagnose the problem.